# Can I access the iOS Guided Access api?

Tags: ios, api

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5509

Is it possible to access this api?  Possibly set it up to bypass the steps when an app is opened?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, no. You should [file a radar](http://bugreport.apple.com) to ask Apple to provide APIs.

Comment: So the user will need to go through the setup process of guided access, manually, and then launch the app?  Any idea how this app is being setup then?  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/parentkit/id600618138?ls=1&mt=8  if not guided access, is it possible to gain access to the api used here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4213

Comment: They're "cheating". They install a provisioning profile that adds the device to their MDM, which enables them to control it remotely. You can read more about MDM here: http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/it-center/deployment-mdm.html.

Comment: Ahh yes Im only slightly familiar with MDM.  Is there a cost for such services and does it need to maintained by a dev such as myself?

Comment: The most common approach is to use a vendor. There's a list here: http://www.enterpriseios.com/story/2012/05/08/Considering_MDM_Compare_30_MDM_vendors_online_and_off_with_our_community_generated_. The cost is different according to the vendor: some consider # of devices, other ones have fixed price...

Comment: So just to keep picking your brain, this becomes legit in the app store, right?  So user picks settings, sends it to the MDM and then the new plist / xml is downloaded into the device?

Comment: Yes you can 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGuidedAccessRestrictionsDelegate_Protocol/

Answer (score 0):

[Guided Access in depth at WWDC 2013](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/202/) (begins at 39:26)

---

[Check if Guided Access is Enabled](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1615173-uiaccessibilityisguidedaccessena) ( iOS 6+ ):

```
UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled()
```

---

[Respond to Guided Access status changes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiaccessibilityguidedaccessstatusdidchangenotification?language=objc) ( iOS 6+ ):

```
UIAccessibilityGuidedAccessStatusDidChangeNotification
```

---

[Add custom restrictions while in Guided Access mode](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiguidedaccessrestrictiondelegate) ( iOS 7+ ):

```
UIGuidedAccessRestrictionDelegate
```

---

[Getting the restriction state for specified restriction](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1621153-uiguidedaccessrestrictionstatefo) ( iOS 7+ ):

Swift:

```
func UIGuidedAccessRestrictionStateForIdentifier(_ restrictionIdentifier: String) -> UIGuidedAccessRestrictionState
```

Obj-C

```
UIGuidedAccessRestrictionState UIGuidedAccessRestrictionStateForIdentifier(NSString *restrictionIdentifier);
```